# Hosting a React App on an Apache Server using rhel7, but my Javascript does not appear to be executing

Tags: reactjs, apache, rhel7

I'm attempting to host a react app on an apache server, and I'm running into the classic blank white page issue. I've reviewed every post that I can find on the subject, but they don't appear to be the same issue that I have.

For simplicity's sake, I've removed my css files from the build, just in case they're further complicating matters.

I set my homepage to './' in my package.json, then ran npm run build on the app.

I'm copying the files over into my apache root in /var/www/html (I'm removing them from the build folder for simplicity's sake)

I modify the html to set the javascript calls to look like this

```
<script type='text/jsx' src='./var/www/html/static/foo.js'>
```

I've added in a [.htaccess file](https://gist.github.com/ywwwtseng/63c36ccb58a25a09f7096bbb602ac1de) at the same level as index.html per the linked instructions. I've run

```
restorecon -r /var/www/html'
```

one level down to ensure the correct connectivity is re-established.

I've updated my .config file with a DocumentRoot of '/var/www/html' and left my DirectoryIndex as index.html. I also added some extra stuff (that should be redundant) from a link in the guide I posted above

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
ServerName localhost
```

The only relevant "new" thing I added was making the server localhost. Someone on reddit suggested it in another post that I found.

When I check my console, I see one request to http://localhost/ that retrieves my html from index.js. But I don't seem to be loading or executing any of my javascript on the other side, so nothing is loading.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I'm not even sure what's causing the issue at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the dang thing working! I'm writing this out as much for my own edification as for anyone else's.

I set the homepage of the app to be '.' and removed the servername component from the config file. I modified the html so that instead of having paths that went './foo/bar' they read '/foo/bar.' Then, I moved the script components of the html tag outside of the body (below it) and everything ran.

I have no idea why this was so much of a hassle-- I just sort of assumed React would work out of the box with something like Apache-- but it's finally, finally done!